# m2Eclipse dependencyManagement section doesn't show graph

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse, pom.xml

I don't know if this is a bug or intended functionality, but the POM editor for m2Eclipse has a wonderful graph representation ('Dependency Graph' tab) and tree ('Dependency Heirarchy' tab) if the dependencies are in the dependency section all by themselves. However, when you move them into the 'dependencyManagement' node (useful for module based projects) these tabs no longer work.

Does anyone know if this is a bug, intended functionality, etc?

EDIT #1: The dependencies in the dependency management section are NOT declared outside of the dependency management section in the parent. They are there to share amongst the child modules; to keep consistency (there was some standard posted somewhere that we're modeling this on).

EDIT #2: The tooling works at the child module level. I am referring to it not working at the parent level.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have POMs with dependencies declared under `dependencyManagement` and they are just shown as expected in the **Dependency Graph** and **Dependency Hierarchy** tabs.

For example, I have a parent POM with:

```
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- SL4J API -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- SLF4J JDK14 Binding  -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency> 
      ...
    </dependencyManagement>
```

And a child POM with:

```
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

And the **Dependency Graph** of the child just works:

[image]

Are the dependencies you moved under `dependencyManagement` actually **also** declared as dependencies? Can you show a simplified `pom.xml` illustrating the problem?

---

> The tooling works at the child module level. I am referring to it not working at the parent level.

Dependencies declared in the `dependencyManagement` element are not `dependencies` of the project (if I declare `foo` in the `dependencyManagement`, I'm still not depending on `foo`). If the parent doesn't declare any `dependencies`, there is nothing to show.

Comment: I edited the question to show the answer to your question (trying not to keep too much in comments) :) - but in short, I think the difference is that in your case you have them outside the dependencyManagement section.