# dependencymanagement for multimodule maven project

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

I have a multimodule maven project, when dependencymanagament tag is provided in parent pom, then m2e fails to import any maven dependency, although maven build is successful. But when dependenctmanagement tag is removed m2e is able to fetch all the dependency jars and my project becomes free from compilation error/ missing jars.

Now, if I remove the dependencymanagement tag from parent pom then all child poms need to be updated with version details which I dont want to do, and its a bd practice also.

So, what should i do to keep the dependencymanagement tag in parent pom, and as well as make elcipse fetch all dependency jars. Tried with enable dependency/disable dependency options in m2e, and even restarting eclipse, they seem not to work.

Comment: Are you importing the top level project or individual modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Pascal's answer to this question [m2Eclipse dependencyManagement section doesn't show graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159008/m2eclipse-dependencymanagement-section-doesnt-show-graph).
Check that the dependencies are declared without version attributes in the sub-modules.
The version attributes from dependencyManagement will only be inherited by the child if the child declares the managed artifact as a dependency.

Comment: yes..this is what I have done....similar to Pascal Thivent... I think I failed to make my problem enough clear. All maven builds are fine, only the failure is that eclipse is unable to fetch them, when I remove the dependencyManagement for parent only then eclipse is enable to fetch the jars.